# Java - Changing pace of CountDown Timer on the fly

Tags: java, android, reference, countdowntimer

I'm trying to make a simple CountDown Timer in Java, that executes a set of instructions repeatedly. I want the user to be able to control the frequency of that execution in real time while the code is running (with a SeekBar on Android).
Here is my attempt so far:

```
final CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(rsvp.wordsOfSentence.length * rsvp.pace, rsvp.pace) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisInFuture) {
            targetTextView.setText(rsvp.wordsOfSentence[rsvp.getCurrentWord()]);
            rsvp.incrementCurrentWord();
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            targetTextView.setText(rsvp.wordsOfSentence[rsvp.getCurrentWord()]);
        }

    };


seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            rsvp.setPace(progress);}
});
```

Method setPace() changes value of int pace (both are set in class RSVP, and rsvp is an object of this class). So I'm trying to pass pace to CountDown Timer as reference, but I'm not sure I do this correctly. Timer executes code, but user has no control over the frequency.

Thanks in advance and forgive me if something is not clear, I just started playing with Java :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with using `CountDownTimer`, you can do this when the seek bar changes:

- Stop the current count down timer
- Create a new count down timer with the new pace
- Start the new count down timer

Alternatively, you can make use the `Handler` class's [`postDelayed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) method to do some action after a delay, but this does the action only once, so you need to call it again and again. I think this makes it easier to change the pace since you can just call `postDelayed` with a different millisecond number when the seek bar changes.

I have written this little `Timer` class which makes use of the above method:

```
public class Timer {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;

    private int interval;

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public Timer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        handler = new Handler ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started)
            startTimer ();
    }
}
```

You can easily get and set the `interval` field with the getters and setters.

Usage:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code to run in each tick of the timer here...
    }
 }, someInterval, true);
// the timer will start automatically if you pass true as the third argument.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Though I'd love some clarification on where inside of your Timer method would you put the actual code to be executed on every interval?

Also:
    public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }

How can I use .run() inside of declaration of run()? It looks a bit confusing for me, could you please explain?

Comment: You just need to pass the code you want to run in the first argument of the constructor of `Timer`. @Adam

Comment: @Adam The `runnable.run()` call is not calling the enclosing `task.run` method. It is calling the `runnable.run` method. `runnable` is the first argument you pass to the constructor.

Comment: I created your Timer class in my project and entered the following code to my OnCreate method in MainActivity in Android Studio:

    Timer timer = new Timer(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    rsvp.displayWordRSVP(targetTextView);
                }
            }, 1000, true);

But I get error saying: Cannot resolve constructor 'Timer(anonymous java.lang.Runnable,int, boolean)'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Adam Are you sure you are using the correct `Timer` class? You might have imported `java.util.Timer` instead. I didn't put a `package` line in the code, but you should add it into your app's package.